# How do I get the parent/origin item of multiple chained child items in a Linq statement?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq statement whose purpose is to get the predecessor item of the selected item.
So my question is: I want to get the very first item of the "chain", not the just the predecessor but the like origin item.

(item; predecessor)

Current behaviour: origin item; null -> ***item0; origin item*** -> **item1, item0**

Wanted behaviour: ***origin item; null*** -> item0; origin item -> **item1; item0**

The data consists of the lineItemID and a predecessorLineItemID (if the item has one, otherwise null), so I have to follow the predecessor of each item, but I have no clue how to realize this as Linq isn't my expertise (as of yet).

```
private static IList<IProductLineItem> GetPredecessorLineItemsWithCustomer(IDocumentBase document)
{
  return document.LineItems
    .Select(item => GetPredecessor(item))
    .OfType<IProductLineItem>()
    .Where(item => ((Document)item.IDocumentBase).Customers.Any(
      customer => customer.CustomerLineItems.Any(customerItem => customerItem.LineItem.Parent == item || customerItem.LineItem == null)))
    .Where(item => ((Document)item.IDocumentBase).Customers.Any(
      customer => customer.CustomerLineItems.Any(customerItem => customerItem.LineItem == item)))
    .ToList();
}

private static ILineItemBase GetPredecessor(ILineItemBase lineItem)
{
  if (DataContext.ReadOnly.TryGet(out Document predecessorDocument, lineItem.PredecessorDocumentId))
    return predecessorDocument.LineItems.SingleOrDefault(
      item => item.LineItemId == lineItem.PredecessorLineItemId);
  else
    return null;
}
```

I actually want to get the logic smh into the GetPredecessor method. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out here! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the length of the chain would be limited to 2 or 3, it would be a self referencing table, you could handle it like it would be two tables, creating a Self-Join.
But here it's not.

For a tree or chain structure there is nothing that will help you.
If your table is 'small' (less than 10.000) load the entire table, that's not a problem,
EF supports Self-References, that means it will resolve Links from one object to another, so you can follow up the chain in C# (but the entire table will be loaded).

The other way is what you just did; load line by line.
This can be done more elegant and 'hidden' if you use virtual Navigation Properties.
As soon as you try to access the predecessor, it will be loaded in background. 
But it's the same line by line loading that you already have.